# PayPal Plus payment wall is not showing. Errors provided but cannot solve them

Tags: magento, paypal

I am integrating the original PayPal's Plus Magento extension.

On the one page checkout page the payment wall is not displayed, instead a normal payment option "Paypal Plus" (radio button) is available which is not the desired checkout solution.

I have found on the web alternative PayPal Plus JS library which is intended for debugging purpose. The library is located here:

```
//www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplusdcc/ppplusdcc.min.js
```

Using that lib results in console logs informing for these validation errors:

```
PP+ Configuration Validation Error. Please review configuration.: required_missing  ppplusdcc.min.js:34:14830
INTERNAL-LOG: renderMessage(), warning: {"type":"required_missing","sourcePath":"/payerEmail"}  ppplusdcc.min.js:34:14830
Invalid 'payerEmail'.  ppplusdcc.min.js:34:14830
INTERNAL-LOG: renderMessage(), warning: {"type":"required_missing","sourcePath":"/payerFirstName"}  ppplusdcc.min.js:34:14830
Invalid 'payerFirstName'.  ppplusdcc.min.js:34:14830
INTERNAL-LOG: renderMessage(), warning: {"type":"required_missing","sourcePath":"/payerLastName"}  ppplusdcc.min.js:34:14830
Invalid 'payerLastName'.  ppplusdcc.min.js:34:14830
INTERNAL-LOG: renderMessage(), warning: {"type":"required_missing","sourcePath":"/payerTaxId"}  ppplusdcc.min.js:34:14830
Invalid 'payerTaxId'.  ppplusdcc.min.js:34:14830
INTERNAL-LOG: renderMessage(), warning: {"type":"unknown_key","actual":"showLoadingIndicator","sourcePath":"","sourceValue":{"approvalUrl":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-7RE57690DW904405G","placeholder":"ppplus","mode":"sandbox","useraction":"commit","buttonLocation":"outside","showLoadingIndicator":true,"country":"DE","language":"de_DE"}}  ppplusdcc.min.js:34:14830
Invalid ''.  ppplusdcc.min.js:34:14830
PP+ Library Config Validation Error
```

I am not able to find any information anywhere on the web regarding these issues. I had searched the whole source of the PHP Library and the Magento extensions and have not found anywhere usage for related parameters.

EDIT: Just to add additional information - the iframe for the payment wall is hidden and the **src** attribute is set to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/inlinepaymentwall/clientlib/public/pages/en_US/notavailableerror.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to integrate with PayPal Plus (checkout solution) using this library or are you expecting the Magento extension to work?

If you are using the PayPal Plus JS library then in that case it appears you have not initialized the above values. The above fields are mandatory. for example without CNPJ or CPF (Payer Tax Id) you will not be able to proceed in Brazil.

Comment: I am integrating the original extension in customized "OneStepCheckout" extension. I am not able to find how/where these missing variables shoud be set.

Comment: same error for me. my country in API is set to country : "de". although in documentation for Germany, payerEmail, payerFirstName, payerFirstName, payerLastName, payerLastName, payerTaxId is not required. is it a bug or issue for Paypal plus itself.